# Determine vergence point on HL2

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, camera, projection, hololens

**Setup**: HoloLens 2, front camera

**Input data**: Gaze origin, gaze direction of user, camera intrinsics

**Desired output**: 2D gaze coordinates

**Objective**: I would like to determine 2D gaze coordinates on the camera projection plane of the front camera of the HoloLens 2. For that, I have placed a virtual camera with representative camera intrinsics of the physical front camera in the scene in Unity3D. Given the gaze origin and direction I could cast a ray into the scene and look for intersection points with the camera projection plane. However, at what depth/distance should I do that? I am not looking for intersections for certain objects but gaze coordinates at all points in time.

**Current approach**:

1. Use Extended Eye Tracking (EET) SDK for Unity3D
2. Retrieve vergence point
3. Convert 3D point into screen space of virtual camera

**Problem**: Can't get a valid vergence distance from EET SDK using following approach. `TryGetVergenceDistance()` always returns false. `GazeDirection` & `GazeOrigin` are valid.

Getting gaze data as follows:

```
var combinedGazeReadingInWorldSpace = extendedEyeGazeDataProvider.GetWorldSpaceGazeReading(ExtendedEyeGazeDataProvider.GazeType.Combined);
```

Modified `ExtendedEyeGazeDataProvider` script, contained method `GetWorldSpaceGazeReading` and `GazeReading` class to return vergence distance as follows:

```
    public class GazeReading
    {
        public Vector3 EyePosition;
        public Vector3 GazeDirection;
        // Added: Vergence distance
        public float VergenceDistance;

        public GazeReading() { }
        public GazeReading(Vector3 position, Vector3 direction)
        {
            EyePosition = position;
            GazeDirection = direction;
        }
    }
```

```
public GazeReading GetWorldSpaceGazeReading(GazeType gazeType, DateTime timestamp)
{
    ...
    ...

    // Added: Vergence distance added to gaze reading
    bool vd_valid = _eyeGazeTrackerReading.TryGetVergenceDistance(out float vd);
    _gazeReading.VergenceDistance = vd_valid ? vd : 1;

    return _gazeReading;
}
```

EDIT:

It seems like vergence distance is not supported on HL2. Can anyone confirm? `_eyeGazeTracker.IsVergenceDistanceSupported` returns `false` on HL2.

Comment: Do I understand the background of your question correct and you want to record the outer camera stream and then basically overlay it with the gaze information? First issue that comes to my head would be differences in the resolution, dimensions and viewport angles ... You could though simply try and go through [`Camera.WorldToViewportPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToViewportPoint.html) for starters ... afaik HoloLens 2 provides not only origin and direction but also the convergence point (so you have the distance/depth)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. If you mean overlay the actual footage of the outer front camera with gaze positions, in principle yes. I think what you suggest might work. So based of that I would get the vergence point (with `rayEndPoint`?) and convert it to viewport/screen coords using `WorldToScreenPoint` on the virtual camera. In theory this makes sense to me. Could you elaborate on your mentioned concerns? Meanwhile I am going to test that

Comment: So rayEndPoint certainly isn't the right way to get the vergence point. If you got any input in that regard, I would appreciate it too:)

Comment: I don't know exactly what SDK you are using or what your input data is and where you get it from ... there is e.g. [Extended Eye Tracking in Unity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/extended-eye-tracking-unity) and `var combinedGazeReadingInWorldSpace = extendedEyeGazeDataProvider.GetWorldSpaceGazeReading(extendedEyeGazeDataProvider.GazeType.Combined, timestamp);.` and then `combinedGazeReadingInWorldSpace.TryGetVergenceDistance(out var distance);` -> `position3D = origin + direction * distance;`

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at that. I was aware of `ExtendedEyeTracking` but couldn't find anything regarding vergence distance

Comment: I have updated the question based on trying to get the vergence distance as you suggested. I currently can't seem to make it work. You got any thoughts on that?